# How can I perform the mutate function (ddply) on a specific group of data in my data frame?

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use the ddply `mutate` function to add 1 to specific rows of my data frame.

**Specific Question**
How do I add 1 to `Duration` when `trackName` is `experimenterTalk` (see row 9 in the sample data frame below)?

Here are the first few rows of my data frame. The name of this data frame is `data_all`.

```
    Time Duration               trackName Comment
   (int)    (dbl)                  (fctr)  (fctr)
1  10173    0.500      playingCaterpillar  (null)
2  11092    0.399          playingChewToy  (null)
3  11946    0.413      playingSpinFanHand  (null)
4  12862    0.382           playingMirror  (null)
5  13651    0.413        playingButtonFan  (null)
6  14423    0.394 playingButtonFiberLight  (null)
7  15241    0.378  playingTwoButtonLights  (null)
8  16052    0.534           playingMagnet  (null)
9   8833    0.000        experimenterTalk  (null)
10  9295    0.585               totalPlay  (null)
```

Here is one of my attempts:

```
    data_all_2 <- ddply(data_all, "trackName"=="experimenterTalk", mutate,
               Duration = Duration + 1
               )
```

But I get this error message:

```
  Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to subset (filter) your data where you instead need to include a grouping variable. You don't actually even need a grouping variable here. For example, in the code below instead of `.(trackName)` you can do `.()`. However, if you do that, `ddply` will add a new `.id` column filled with `NA`.

```
data_all_2 = ddply(data_all, .(trackName) , mutate,
      Duration = ifelse(trackName=="experimenterTalk", Duration + 1, Duration))
```

The `dplyr` package is faster and has largely superceded `plyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data_all_2 = data_all %>% 
  mutate(Duration = ifelse(trackName=="experimenterTalk", Duration + 1, Duration)))
```

In base R, you could do:

```
data_all$Duration[data_all$trackName=="experimenterTalk"] = 
          data_all$Duration[data_all$trackName=="experimenterTalk"] + 1
```